# programa em C para calcular a media , mediana e uantidade de numeros impares

Tags: c

A proposta da questão é essa

:Faça um programa em C que leia do usuário um vetor de inteiros com n posições no
intervalo [5, 200]. Ler repetitivamente o valor de n até que um valor válido seja digitado pelo
usuário. Após a leitura dos n valores digitados pelo usuário algumas estatísticas devem ser
extraídas deste vetor:
a) Imprimir na tela a Média do vetor;
b) Imprimir na tela a Mediana do vetor;
c) Imprimir na tela a quantidade de números ímpares e pares do vetor.

Obs.: Os números reais devem ser impressos na tela com precisão de duas casas
decimais;

Assumir que o vetor já é digitado ordenado pelo usuário;
A média aritmética simples corresponde a , onde x corresponde a cada elemento
do vetor com n posições.
O cálculo da mediana de dados ordenados de amostras de tamanho n pode ser
realizado da seguinte forma: se n for ímpar, a mediana será o elemento central . Se
n for par, a mediana será o resultado da média simples entre os elementos e +1;

tentei resolver mas não estou acostumado com esse sistema preciso de tipagem de variaveis na linguAgem C, aqui esta o meu código(esta bem precário):

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(){

int comeco =0, fim =0;
int v[1000];
int tam = fim - comeco;
int m = 0,md, impar = 0;
float media, mediana;

do{

printf("Digite um numero no intervalo de 5 a 200");
scanf("%i %i", &comeco, &fim);
getchar();

}while(comeco < 5 || fim > 200);

int i = 0;

for (int j = comeco; j < fim; j++) {
    v[i] = j;
    i+=1;
    if(v[i] % 2 != 0){
        impar += 1;
        }
}
for (int me = 0; me < tam; me++) {

    m += v[me];
}
media = (float)m/(float)tam;
printf("%.2f\n", media);
printf("%i impar \n", impar );

if(tam % 2 == 0){
    md = (tam/2);
    mediana = ((float)v[md]+ (float)v[md-1])/2;
}else{
    md=(tam/2);
    mediana=(float)v[md];
}
printf("%.2f", mediana);
```

}

Comment: Pelo enunciado eu entendo que você deve fazer a leitura dos n elementos do vetor e não atribuir um valor sequencial de começo até fim.

Comment: sim, eu devo fazer uma leitura das n posições no vetor mas os valores tem que estar no intervalo de 5-200. atribui duas variáveis("comeco"e "fim") para eu conseguir atrubuir os valores no loop começando da posição 0, no caso da variável "tam" que é o fim - o comeco da sequencia é so para eu conseguir fazer as contas da media e mediana com as posições certas no array. Eu tenho quase certeza que é um erro de conversão dos tipos das variáveis mas não estou encontrando onde exatamente o erro está....

Comment: Creio que existem vários problemas de entendimento. Lendo o enunciado entendo que você deve ler a quantidade de valores a serem tratados (`n`, ou no seu caso `tam`) e depois fazer a leitura destes `n` valores onde cada valor lido deve estar em [5, 200] (é um único valor e não um par de valores). Note que onde declarou `int tam = fim - comeco;` o valor de `tam` será zero pois está imediatamente após `int comeco =0, fim =0;`.

Comment: está pergunta tem o algoritmo para media e mediana: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490264/diminuir-o-c%c3%b3digo/490322#490322](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490264/diminuir-o-c%c3%b3digo/490322#490322)