# Diminuir o código

Tags: c

sou novo na programação estou fazendo um projeto mas ele está ficando muito grande, queria saber se alguem poderia me ajudar a diminuir.
Segue abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

void MostraMedia (){
    FILE *a;
    if((a = fopen ("media.txt", "wb+")) == NULL){
    printf ("O arquivo nao existe.");
    exit(1);
}

    int ano [] = {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,2017};
    int mortes [] = {1028, 18, 172, 2, 340, 97, 1075, 13, 150, 0, 338, 113, 1090, 6, 140, 1, 354, 118, 1124, 8, 116, 0, 423, 136, 1144, 10, 115, 1, 407, 176, 1178, 7, 108, 1, 500, 173, 1139, 10, 151,3, 526, 148, 1151, 6, 151, 3, 566, 153, 1205, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166 , 1202, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166, 1212, 6, 137, 1, 678, 169, 1280, 7, 113, 2, 733, 187, 1220, 9, 116, 2, 769, 188, 1285, 8, 126, 3, 835, 169, 1288, 8, 103, 6, 900, 202, 1227, 11, 106, 2, 838, 194, 1317, 9, 113, 2, 959, 201, 1266, 8, 78, 2, 975, 215};
    
    
    int n, i, anos, soma;
    float media;
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2000 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    for (i = 6; i <= 11; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    media = soma/6;
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2001 é: %.2f\n", media); 
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 12; i <= 17; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2002 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 18; i <= 23; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2003 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 24; i <= 29; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2004 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 30; i <= 35; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2005 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 36; i <= 41; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2006 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 42; i <= 47; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2007 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 48; i <= 53; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2008 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 54; i <= 59; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2009 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 60; i <= 65; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2010 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 66; i <= 71; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2011 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 72; i <= 77; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2012 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 78; i <= 83; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2013 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 84; i <= 89; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2014 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 90; i <= 95; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2015 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 96; i <= 101; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2016 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
    soma = 0;
    media = 0;
    
    for (i = 102; i <= 107; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
        media = soma/6;
    }
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano 2017 é: %.2f\n", media);
    fprintf(a,"\n%d", media);
    
   
}

void CasoAno (){
    
    int ano [] = {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,2017};
    int mortes [] = {1028, 18, 172, 2, 340, 97, 1075, 13, 150, 0, 338, 113, 1090, 6, 140, 1, 354, 118, 1124, 8, 116, 0, 423, 136, 1144,10, 115, 1, 407, 176, 1178, 7, 108, 1, 500, 173, 1139, 10, 151,3, 526, 148, 1151, 6, 151, 3, 566, 153, 1205, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166 , 1202, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166, 1212, 6, 137, 1, 678, 169, 1280, 7, 113, 2, 733, 187, 1220, 9, 116, 2, 769, 188, 1285, 8, 126, 3, 835, 169, 1288, 8, 103, 6, 900, 202, 1227, 11, 106, 2, 838, 194, 1317, 9, 113, 2, 959, 201, 1266, 8, 78, 2, 975, 215};
    
    int n, i, anos, soma;
    
    soma = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2000 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;

    for (i = 6; i <= 11; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2001 é: %d\n", soma); 
    
    soma = 0;
    
    
    for (i = 12; i <= 17; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2002 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;

    
    for (i = 18; i <= 23; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2003 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 24; i <= 29; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2004 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 30; i <= 35; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2005 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 36; i <= 41; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2006 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 42; i <= 47; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2007 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 48; i <= 53; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2008 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;

    
    for (i = 54; i <= 59; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2009 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 60; i <= 65; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2010 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 66; i <= 71; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2011 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 72; i <= 77; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2012 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 78; i <= 83; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2013 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 84; i <= 89; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2014 é: %d\n", soma);
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 90; i <= 95; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2015 é: %d\n", soma);

    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 96; i <= 101; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2016 é: %d\n", soma);

    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 102; i <= 107; i++){
        soma = soma + mortes[i];
    }
    printf ("O total de mortes do ano 2017 é: %d\n", soma);

    
    
}

void MostraMediana(){
    float mediana;
    int i, j, aux;

    int ano [] = {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,2017};
    int mortes [] = {1028, 18, 172, 2, 340, 97, 1075, 13, 150, 0, 338, 113, 1090, 6, 140, 1, 354, 118, 1124, 8, 116, 0, 423, 136, 1144,10, 115, 1, 407, 176, 1178, 7, 108, 1, 500, 173, 1139, 10, 151,3, 526, 148, 1151, 6, 151, 3, 566, 153, 1205, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166 , 1202, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166, 1212, 6, 137, 1, 678, 169, 1280, 7, 113, 2, 733, 187, 1220, 9, 116, 2, 769, 188, 1285, 8, 126, 3, 835, 169, 1288, 8, 103, 6, 900, 202, 1227, 11, 106, 2, 838, 194, 1317, 9, 113, 2, 959, 201, 1266, 8, 78, 2, 975, 215};
    
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        for (j = i+1; j <= 6; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[3] + mortes[4]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2000 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 6; i <= 11; i++){
        for (j = i+1; j <= 12; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[9] + mortes[10]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2001 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 12; i <= 17; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 18; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[15] + mortes[16]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2002 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 18; i <= 23; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 24; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[21] + mortes[22]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2003 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 24; i <= 29; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 30; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[27] + mortes[28]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2004 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 30; i <= 35; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 36; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[33] + mortes[34]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2005 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 36; i <= 41; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 42; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[39] + mortes[40]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2006 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 42; i <= 47; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 48; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[45] + mortes[46]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2007 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 48; i <= 53; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 54; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[51] + mortes[52]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2008 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 54 ; i <= 59; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 60; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[57] + mortes[58]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2009 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 60 ; i <= 65; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 66; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[63] + mortes[64]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2010 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 66 ; i <= 71; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 72; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[69] + mortes[70]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2011 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 72 ; i <= 77; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 78; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[77] + mortes[78]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2012 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 78 ; i <= 83; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 84; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[81] + mortes[82]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2013 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 84 ; i <= 89; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 90; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[87] + mortes[88]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2014 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 90 ; i <= 95; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 91; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[93] + mortes[94]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2015 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 96 ; i <= 101; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 102; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[99] + mortes[100]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2016 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
    
    for (i = 102 ; i <= 107; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 109; j++){
            if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);
            aux = mortes[i];
            mortes[i] = mortes[j];
            mortes[j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    mediana = (mortes[106] + mortes[107]) / 2;
    printf ("A mediana do ano 2017 é: %.2f\n", mediana);
}

void MostraModa(){
    float moda,v_conta;
    int i, j, v_moda[i];

    int ano [] = {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,2017};
    int mortes [] = {1028, 18, 172, 2, 340, 97, 1075, 13, 150, 0, 338, 113, 1090, 6, 140, 1, 354, 118, 1124, 8, 116, 0, 423, 136, 1144,10, 115, 1, 407, 176, 1178, 7, 108, 1, 500, 173, 1139, 10, 151,3, 526, 148, 1151, 6, 151, 3, 566, 153, 1205, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166 , 1202, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166, 1212, 6, 137, 1, 678, 169, 1280, 7, 113, 2, 733, 187, 1220, 9, 116, 2, 769, 188, 1285, 8, 126, 3, 835, 169, 1288, 8, 103, 6, 900, 202, 1227, 11, 106, 2, 838, 194, 1317, 9, 113, 2, 959, 201, 1266, 8, 78, 2, 975, 215};
    
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        for (j = 0 + 1; i <= 6; j++){
            if (mortes[i] == mortes[j]){
                    v_moda[i]++;
                    if (v_moda[i] > v_conta){
                        v_conta = v_moda[i];
                        moda = mortes[i];
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("A moda do ano 2000 eh: %.2f", moda);
    
    for (i = 6; i <= 11; i++){
        for (j = 0 + 1; i <= 12; j++){
            if (mortes[i] == mortes[j]){
                    v_moda[i]++;
                    if (v_moda[i] > v_conta){
                        v_conta = v_moda[i];
                        moda = mortes[i];
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("A moda do ano 2001 eh: %.2f", moda);
    
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    float media;
    int i,soma,n,anos;

    int ano [] = {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,2017};
    int mortes [] = {1028, 18, 172, 2, 340, 97, 1075, 13, 150, 0, 338, 113, 1090, 6, 140, 1, 354, 118, 1124, 8, 116, 0, 423, 136, 1144,10, 115, 1, 407, 176, 1178, 7, 108, 1, 500, 173, 1139, 10, 151,3, 526, 148, 1151, 6, 151, 3, 566, 153, 1205, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166 , 1202, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166, 1212, 6, 137, 1, 678, 169, 1280, 7, 113, 2, 733, 187, 1220, 9, 116, 2, 769, 188, 1285, 8, 126, 3, 835, 169, 1288, 8, 103, 6, 900, 202, 1227, 11, 106, 2, 838, 194, 1317, 9, 113, 2, 959, 201, 1266, 8, 78, 2, 975, 215};
    int op;

    //Fazer o menu de opções;
    printf ("Ola!\nEsse programa mostra as opções disponiveis para visualizar esses dados!");

    do{
        printf ("\nEscolha:\n1- Ver o total de mortes por ano:");
        printf ("\n2- Ver a média de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\n3- Ver a mediana de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\n4- Ver a moda de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\n5- Ver a variancia de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\n6- Ver o desvio padrao de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\nOpcao: ");
        scanf ("%d", &op);

        while ((op!=1)&&(op!=2)&&(op!=3)&&(op!=4)&&(op!=5)&&(op!=6)){
            printf ("\nPor favor digite uma das opcoes!!\n");
            scanf ("%d", &op);
        }

    switch (op){
        case 1: //Mostra a o total de mortes
        CasoAno();
        break;
        case 2:  //Mostra a média
        MostraMedia();
        break;
        case 3:
        MostraMediana(); //Mostra mediana
        break;
        case 4:
        MostraModa();
        break;
    }
    

    }while (op!=0);





    //Fazer as funções com moda, variância e desvio padrão;
    //Fazer a manipulação de arquivos;
    //Fazer a ordenação;
    



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Até tem, mas seria interessante você ao menos explicar o que o código deveria fazer.

Comment: Você avaliou o uso de array bidimensional? Para calcular uma média é melhor somar dentro do loop e fazer a divisão após o término do loop. Este comando `if (mortes[i] > mortes[j]);` não me parece estar certo (executar o comando nulo caso a condição seja verdadeira). Por qual motivo você fica declarando e atribuindo valores a variáveis locais (por ex. ano), não seria melhor passar como parâmetro?

Answer (score 0):

olá, vi que você tem muitos "for" iguais por todo seu código, já pensou em criar uma função que os "exclua"?
Você pode passar os dados por parametro para uma função com apenas 1 for.
Exemplo:

```
   float calculaMedia(int a, int b, int [] mortes) {

      int i, soma=0;
      float media=0;

         for (i = a; i <= b; i++){
            soma = soma + mortes[i];
            media = soma/6;
          }
         return media;
   }
```

Comment: Então, teria como eu colocar um for dentro de outro for, de uma forma em que ele iria calculando a media de 6 em 6 números. Tipo ele inicia em 0 e vai até o vetor de indice 6, aí calcula a media, mostra o resultado e depois continua só que começando pelo indice 7 e assim por diante. Desculpa se ficou confuso, sou novo nisso :/

Comment: @JoaoLochini isso mesmo... só use nomes diferentes para o índice de cada laço for subjacente

Answer (score 0):

Na função `MostraMedia` pode ser:

```
for (i=0; i<18; i++) {
    soma = 0;
    for (j=0; j<6; j++)
        soma += mortes[i*6+j];
    media = soma /6;
    printf ("A media de mortes do ano %d é: %.2f\n", ano[i], media);
    fprintf(a,"%d\n", media);
}
```

Nas demais faça de modo similar.
Mas reforço que o uso de um array bidimensional facilitaria.

Answer (score 0):

use laços for para iterar os anos também, passe os dados por parâmetros, invés de declarar duplicatas, ou ainda por globais (menos aconselhado), refatorei o código aplicando tais ideias:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>


struct DadosAnos {
    DadosAnos() {}
    int inicio, fim;
    int *valores;
};

void mostraMedia (DadosAnos dados, FILE* arquivo){
    for (int ano = dados.inicio; ano <= dados.fim; ano++) {
        float media = 0;
        //indice onde começa os dado do respectivo ano
        int index_ano = (ano-dados.inicio)*6;
        int i = index_ano;
        int e = index_ano + 6;
        for (; i < e; i++) {
            media += (float)dados.valores[i];
        }
        media /= 6.0f;
        printf ("A media de mortes do ano %d é: %.2f\n", ano, media);
        //se um arquivo for passada como parametro, o resultado é impresso nele
        if (arquivo)
            fprintf(arquivo,"%d: %.2f\n", ano, media);
    }
}

void casosAno (DadosAnos dados, FILE* arquivo){
    for (int ano = dados.inicio; ano <= dados.fim; ano++) {
        int soma = 0;
        //indice onde começa os dado do respectivo ano
        int index_ano = (ano-dados.inicio)*6;
        int i = index_ano;
        int e = index_ano + 6;
        for (; i < e; i++) {
            soma += dados.valores[i];
        }

        printf ("A total de mortes do ano %d é: %d\n", ano, soma);
        //se um arquivo for passada como parametro, o resultado é impresso nele
        if (arquivo)
            fprintf(arquivo,"%d: %d\n", ano, soma);
    }
}
void ordenar(int* casos) {
    bool ordenado = true;
    do {
        ordenado = true;
        for (int i = 0;i<5;i++) {
            if (casos[i]>casos[i+1]) {
                //inverter
                int temp = casos[i];
                casos[i] = casos[i+1];
                casos[i+1] = temp;
                //===
                ordenado = false;
            }
        }
    } while (!ordenado);
}
void mostraMediana(DadosAnos dados, FILE* arquivo){
    for (int ano = dados.inicio; ano <= dados.fim; ano++) {
        float soma = 0;
        //indice onde começa os dado do respectivo ano
        int index_ano = (ano-dados.inicio)*6;

        //reordenar em ordem crescente
        ordenar(&(dados.valores[index_ano]));
        
        float mediana = (float)(dados.valores[index_ano+2] + dados.valores[index_ano+3]) / 2.0f;

        printf ("A mediana de mortes do ano %d é: %.2f\n", ano, mediana);
        //se um arquivo for passada como parametro, o resultado é impresso nele
        if (arquivo)
            fprintf(arquivo,"%d: %.2f\n", ano, mediana);
    }
}

void mostraModa(DadosAnos dados, FILE* arquivo){
    for (int ano = dados.inicio; ano <= dados.fim; ano++) {
        float soma = 0;
        //indice onde começa os dado do respectivo ano
        int index_ano = (ano-dados.inicio)*6;
        int contador[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 6; i2++) {
                if(i != i2 &&
                    dados.valores[index_ano+i] == dados.valores[index_ano+i2])
                    contador[i]++;
            }
        }
        int maior_valor = 0;
        int moda = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (contador[i]>maior_valor) {
                maior_valor = contador[i];
                moda = dados.valores[index_ano+i];
            }
        }
        printf ("A moda das mortes do ano %d é: %d\n", ano, moda);
        //se um arquivo for passada como parametro, o resultado é impresso nele
        if (arquivo)
            fprintf(arquivo,"%d: %d\n", ano, moda);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //carregar dados de um arquivo, ou preenchelos...
    int mortes[] = {1028, 18, 172, 2, 340, 97, 1075, 13, 150, 0, 338, 113, 1090, 6, 140, 1, 354, 118, 1124, 8, 116, 0, 423, 136, 1144, 10, 115, 1, 407, 176, 1178, 7, 108, 1, 500, 173, 1139, 10, 151,3, 526, 148, 1151, 6, 151, 3, 566, 153, 1205, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166 , 1202, 7, 139, 3, 625, 166, 1212, 6, 137, 1, 678, 169, 1280, 7, 113, 2, 733, 187, 1220, 9, 116, 2, 769, 188, 1285, 8, 126, 3, 835, 169, 1288, 8, 103, 6, 900, 202, 1227, 11, 106, 2, 838, 194, 1317, 9, 113, 2, 959, 201, 1266, 8, 78, 2, 975, 215};

    DadosAnos valores;
    valores.inicio = 2000;
    valores.fim = 2017;
    valores.valores = &(mortes[0]);

    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    printf ("Ola!\nEsse programa mostra as opções disponiveis para visualizar esses dados!");

    FILE* arquivo = 0;
    int op;
    do {
        printf ("\nEscolha:\n1- Ver o total de mortes por ano:");
        printf ("\n2- Ver a média de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\n3- Ver a mediana de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\n4- Ver a moda de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\n5- Ver a variancia de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\n6- Ver o desvio padrao de mortes por ano: ");
        printf ("\nOpcao: ");
        scanf ("%d", &op);

        //mais prático, verificar se está fora da faixa...
        while (op < 1 || op > 6){
            printf ("\nPor favor digite uma das opcoes!!\n");
            scanf ("%d", &op);
        }

        switch (op){
        case 1:
            arquivo = fopen ("casos.txt", "wb+");
            casosAno(valores,arquivo);
            fclose(arquivo);
            break;
        case 2:
            arquivo = fopen ("media.txt", "wb+");
            mostraMedia(valores,arquivo);
            fclose(arquivo);
            break;
        case 3:
            arquivo = fopen ("mediana.txt", "wb+");
            mostraMediana(valores,arquivo);
            fclose(arquivo);
            break;
        case 4:
            arquivo = fopen ("moda.txt", "wb+");
            mostraModa(valores,arquivo);
            fclose(arquivo);
            break;
        }
    } while (op!=0);
    return 0;
}
```